# Python C API check if int64 is unsigned

Tags: python, c

I'm writing a Python3 script with some computationally heavy sections in C, using the Python C API. When dealing with int64s, I can't figure out how to ensure that an input number is an unsigned int64; that is , if it's smaller than 0. As the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#numbers) suggests, I'm using `PyArg_ParseTuple()` with the formatter `K` - which does **not** check for overflow. Here is my C code:

```
static PyObject* from_uint64(PyObject* self, PyObject*){
    uint64_t input;
    PyObject* output;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "K", &input)){
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Wrong input: expected unsigned 64-bit integer.");
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

However, calling the function with a negative argument throws no error, and the input number is casted to unsigned. E.g., `from_uint64(-1)` will result in `input=2^64-2`. As expected, since there's no overflow check.

What would be the correct way of determining whether the input number is negative, possibly before parsing it?

Comment: there is no *overflow* with unsigned integers. C specifies that they follow modulo arithmetic.

Comment: also do note that `K` **does not parse `uint64_t` but `unsigned long long`**, hence it is not strictly correct to assume that `uint64_t` is the same as unsigned long long.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks for the correction, I will add the proper type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little modification from @Ctx 's answer:

The solution is to first parse the input as an object (so, not directly from `args`), then check its type:

```
static PyObject* from_uint64(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    PyObject* output;
    PyObject* input_obj;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &input_obj)){
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "Wrong input: expected py object.");
    }
    unsigned long long input = PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(input_obj);
    if(input == -1 && PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "Parameter must be an unsigned integer type, but got %s", Py_TYPE
        (input_obj)->tp_name);
    }
```

This code, as expected, works on any input in [0, 2^64-1] and throws error on integers outside the boundaries as well as illegal types like float, string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
unsigned long long input = PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(args);
```

You can then check with

```
if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
    // handle out of range here
}
```

if the number was unsuitable for an `unsigned long long`.

See also [the Python 3 API documentation on Integer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem I still have is the case in which the input number is small - e.g. if calling `from_uint64(2)` now throws an error. Should I do some kind of casting from Python? I want to accept any number in the range [0, 2^64-1].

Comment: @FTeod Which error is thrown? I do not see a reason, why the input `2`  should be a problem.

Comment: I get `TypeError: an integer is required`. The code being the three lines above, and inside the `if(PyErr_Occurred()) { PyErr_Print(); return NULL;}`